# Android Wear ads don't show

Tags: android, admob

Is there any way to monetize Android Wear(with ads mainly)?
I tried Admob as usual and with `play-services-wearable` but ads don't show any way.

Comment: Android Wear does not have direct internet connectivity and also there is no implementation of admob available for Wear devices yet

Comment: Ok, so is there any other Ad company that provide ads? I think there might be way to do that with phone internet connection.

Comment: Even if you handle the internet part, think from the usability point, there is not enough space available for kind of ads that we are seeing on mobile devices. However you will find some large companies/widely used apps can show ads from their own platform with carefully designed interface.